# Custom cell imageView shifts to left side when editing tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a tableView that I need to be able to delete items from, however, when I put it back from editing mode, the imageView from my custom cell gets shifted over to the left side. Here's some relevant code and images:

[image]
[image]

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotificationsTableViewCell
    cell.storiesLabel.text = stories[indexPath.row].name
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = false

    if stories[indexPath.row].notificationBool == true {
        cell.notificationImageView.image = UIImage(named: "notifications_filled.png")
    }
    else {
        cell.notificationImageView.image = UIImage(named: "notifications.png")
    }

    return cell
}

func editFollowedStoriesTableView() {
    if tableView.editing == true {
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    }
    else {
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    if(self.tableView.editing){

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete

    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None

}
```

How can I prevent the second picture from happening? 
Any help is very much appriciated!

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, I am. Do you want to see the constraints?

Comment: Yes. Can You post a screenshot of that?

Comment: Sure thing. http://imgur.com/a/niVKu

Comment: have you tried reloading the table view after you end editing ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work unfortunately. I also realized it's not only after editing. http://imgur.com/4IV5BGg

Answer (score 0):

You have some conflicting auto layout constraints. You need to delete one of the following constraints on the UIImageView:

```
Width
Leading Space to: Label
Trailing space to: Superview
```

Here, The leading space and trailing space constraints define the width of the imageView. Then you added the width constraint that does the same thing. Now if you want your image view to have a fixed width delete either the leading space or trailing space constraint. If you don't need to have a fixed width, delete the width constraint.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. I tried deleting each one, it still shows up the same way. I also noticed now that it also occurs when I swipe out of bounds. Here's a gif: http://imgur.com/4IV5BGg